# Why can't Kotlin implicitly upcast Array of String into Array of Any?

Tags: arrays, generics, kotlin, casting, any

The following code implicitly upcasts a String into Any.

```
    val s = "some string"
    val upcasted: Any = s
```

However, the following does not compile (type mismatch):

```
    val s = arrayOf("some string")
    val upcasted: Array<Any> = s
```

You can successfully cast to `Array<Any>` as shown:

```
    val s = arrayOf("some string")
    val upcasted: Array<Any> = s as Array<Any>
```

However, this gives the warning `"Unchecked cast: Array<String> to Array<Any>"`.
The same logic **does** appear to work with Lists, so is the internal implementation of Array incompatible with this type of casting? Perhaps it because of the in-memory representation of Arrays?

Comment: Have a look at variance on the [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance)

Comment: Good link, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't safely cast a type to a supertype or subtype like this, because an `Array<String>` does not qualify as an `Array<Any>`. If you tried to put a Double in your supposed `Array<Any>`, it would throw an exception, because the actual type is a String array. Arrays are a special case of generics that don't have type erasure, so they are locked to the type they were instantiated with.

What you could do is cast it to an `Array<out Any>`, because you can safely use it that way. You can pull Strings *out* of the array and they qualify as instances of Any. The reverse is not true. You can't put any instance of Any and its subclasses into a String array.

When it comes to List, you can cast it to a List with the supertype type and you don't even have to manually cast it. It's safe so the cast can be done implicitly.

```
val s = listOf("some string")
val upcasted: List<Any> = s // implicit cast
```

So why don't you have to cast to `List<out Any>`? The List interface doesn't have any functions that allow you to add stuff to it. It is defined with an `out`-projected type in its declaration, so when you type `List<Any>` it is already the same thing as a `List<out Any>`

If you try to do this with a MutableList, which accepts putting items into it and is not defined with an `out`-projected type, then you will run into the same warning as you did with the array.

```
val s = mutableListOf("some string")
val upcasted: MutableList<Any> = s as MutableList<Any> // warning here and implicit cast impossible
```

The difference between this and the Array is that there is type-erasure, so you won't have a runtime exception if you try to add some non-String to this list. But there is the possibility of hidden bugs if you are not careful, hence the warning.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Very interesting about List vs MutableList. I've come across similar issues for years in Java too, not totally understanding it until now.